# Why does tomcat creates an MBean with Catalina:type=ServerClassLoader,name=common

Tags: tomcat, jmx

i was going through tomcat 6 source code which in Bootstrap.java creates a MBean with the following line "Catalina:type=ServerClassLoader,name="+common. Line 180.

I am unable to understand why it does,were is the need of Creating an MBean to manage a ClassLoader. My best bet is, it is trying to managed class loading. I will really appreciate anyone explaining it.

Thanks
Jamal (Any kind of help is much appreciated).

Answer (score 0):

I think your best bet is generally correct. The [JMX MBeanServer API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/management/MBeanServer.html) specifies a number of operations where a class loader is specified in the form of an ObjectName, rather than passing one directly (which in the case of a remote registration would not be possible), so an ObjectName is an indirect reference to an actual classloader. Consider this method in MBeanServer:

[createMBean(java.lang.String, javax.management.ObjectName, javax.management.ObjectName)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/management/MBeanServer.html#createMBean%28java.lang.String,%20javax.management.ObjectName,%20javax.management.ObjectName%29)

The second ObjectName is the classloder to be used where the class named in the String arg can be loaded from. I have found that, especially in concert with standard ObjectName conventions, that publshing a classloader MBean simplifies other management tasks, and is also a friendly gesture to others that may attempt their own extensions.